# Numpy Reshape to obtain monthly means from data

Tags: python, numpy, mean, reshape

I'm trying to obtain monthly means from an observed precipitation data set for the period 1901-2015. The current shape of my prec variable is `(1380(time), 360(lon), 720(lat))`, with 1380 being the number of months over a 115 year period. I have been informed that to calculate monthly means, the most effective way is to conduct an `np.reshape` command on the `prec` variable to split the array up into months and years. However I am not sure what the best way to do this is. I was also wondering if there was a way in Python to select specific months of the year, as I will be producing plots for each month of the year.

I have been attempting to reshape the `prec` variable with the code below. However I am not sure how to do this correctly:

```
#Set Source Folder
sys.path.append('../../..')
SrcFld = ("/export/silurian/array-01/obs/CRU/")

#Retrieve Data
data_path = ''

example = (str(SrcFld) + 'cru_ts4.00.1901.2015.pre.dat.nc') 
Data = Dataset(example)

#Create Prec Mean Array and reshape to get monthly means
Prec_mean = np.zeros((360,720))

#Retrieve Variables
Prec = Data.variables['pre'][:]
lats = Data.variables['lat'][:]
lons = Data.variables['lon'][:]

np.reshape(Prec, ())

#Get Annual/Monthly Average
Prec_mean =np.mean(Prec,axis=0)
```

Any guidance on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to compute the mean of? You have one time and two spatial coordinates, I assume you have some variable (dependent on these coordinates) too? Is this `'pre' `? Please be more specific on the array shapes that you have.

Comment: Better yet show us don't tell us with a [reporoducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't have your CPU so we don't know what is in *Data*.

Comment: Please include a minimal example of ```Prec```, say ten or fifteen rows (```Prec[15,...]```), with a description of each axis.

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet will first dice the precipitation array year-wise. We can then use that array to get the monthly average of precipitation.

```py
>>> prec = np.random.rand(1380,360,720)
>>> ind = np.arange(12,1380,12)
>>> yearly_split = np.array(np.split(prec, ind, axis=0))

>>> yearly_split.shape
(115, 12, 360, 720)

>>> monthly_mean = yearly_split.mean(axis=0)
>>> monthly_mean.shape
(12, 360, 720)
```